# How to update a Javascript object with a function

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, getjson

Basically I have a object which defines some properties for a [Highchart](http://www.highcharts.com) chart:

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line',
        marginRight: 130,
        marginBottom: 25
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y + '°C';
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -10,
        y: 100,
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: aCosts
    }]
};
```

And I want to update this object from a file (ajax call) like so:

```
$.getJSON(
    "handler.php",
    function (oJSON) {
        var sName,
            sCost,
            aRow;
        for (sName in oJSON) {
            aRow = [];
            //categories = [];
            if (oJSON.hasOwnProperty(sName)) {
                aRow.push(sName);
                categories.push(sName);
            }
            // Create the chart
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        }
    }
);
```

The problem is, I can't pass the new value to options as it states that categories is not defined. I've tried using:

```
options.categories.push(sName)
options[categories].push(sName)
```

And none work.

How can I update the value of categories inside my options object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `options` is visible from the `$.JSON` call, this should work:

```
options.xAxis.categories.push( sName );
```

If you look at the structure of your `options` object, you see, that `categories` is below the property `xAxis`. Thus you should address is like that.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define categories first like so:

```
options.categories = [];
```

then you can push things into this array.

Edit: You could place `categories: []` in your json to begin with also.

Comment: I did not see that categories falls under the xAxis object already in your JSON. So as others have already pointed out, you just need to access it in the right spot, within xAxis.